# Generic Visual studio solution template

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

We are working asp.net projects where user customizations are released in a new project/solution called as ADDINS (for our comfort). The Structure is soemthign like this:

```
Solution_ClientName.sln 
     -> FVAddins                      //( Website)
     ->FVAddins_ClientCode_BL.csproj      //(class library project)
     -> SqlDbProject                      //(Sql Database project)
```

I want to know is there any way in Visual Studio , so that I can create a generic template of the same. And whenever , I have to create a new solution, I just need to fill the dynamic parts like `ClientName` and `ClientCode` and the directory structure will be ready.

Kindly note,
I do not require it using Programatically. As here's a time constraint. But programmatic approach is welcome too. I will look into that too.

### Just To Help

I want it like Microsoft word template file where we have template something like `<SomeField>` and its get replaced by your desired text, in all over the file.

Comment: you could use a config file to this effect, all you would need to do is specify each dynamic part in the config file and load that into the solution on startup

Answer (score 0):

You could use a config file to this effect, all you would need to do is specify each dynamic part in the config file and load that into the solution on start-up.

Then you have a copy of the same config with different values for each copy of the template you create